# Eliminar elementos de un array bidimensional en C#

Tags: c#, array, funciones

estoy haciendo un programa que simula una base de datos de una librería, la cual debe permitir hacer operaciones tales como ingresar nuevos libros, darlos de baja, hacer consultas y demás, este es el código que tengo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int opcio = 0, comptador = 0, posicioVector1 = 0;
            string[,] llibres = new string[100, 5];
            char final = ' ';
            bool acabar = false;

            while (!acabar)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                opcio = menuPrincipal();
                switch (opcio)
                {
                    case 1:
                        afegeixLlibre(ref llibres, ref comptador);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        eliminaLlibre(ref llibres, ref comptador);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        llistaLlibres(llibres, comptador);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        consultaTitol(llibres);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        sortida();
                        break;
                }

                final = espera();

                if (final == 'n')
                {
                    acabar = true;
                }

            }
        }



        static void afegeixLlibre(ref string[,] llibres, ref int comptador)
        {

            if (comptador == 100)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No es poden afegir més llibres, prova eliminant algun");
            }
            else
            {

                for (int x = comptador; x < comptador + 1; x++)
                {

                    for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
                    {

                        if (y == 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Entra el ISBN");
                            llibres[x, y] = Console.ReadLine();
                        }else if (y == 1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Entra el títol del llibre");
                            llibres[x, y] = Console.ReadLine();
                        }else if (y == 2)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Entra el autor del llibre");
                            llibres[x, y] = Console.ReadLine();
                        }else if (y == 3)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Entra la editorial del llibre");
                            llibres[x, y] = Console.ReadLine();
                        }else if (y == 4)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Entra el any de edició");
                            llibres[x, y] = Console.ReadLine();
                        }

                    }
                }

                comptador++;

            }

        }

        static void eliminaLlibre(ref string[,] llibres, ref int comptador)
        {
            string isbn;
            bool trobat = false;
            int posicioX = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Entra el ISBN del llibre que vols donar de baixa:");
            isbn = Console.ReadLine();


            for (int x = 0; x < comptador; x++)
            {
                if (llibres[x, 0] == isbn)
                {
                    trobat = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    posicioX++;
                }
            }


            if (!trobat)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Llibre trobat a la base de dades, donant de baixa");
                comptador--;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No s'ha pogut trobar el libre, Comrpvoa que el ISBN sigui correcte o que el llibre es trobi a la base de dades");
            }

        }

        static void llistaLlibres(string[,] llibres, int comptador)
        {

            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("Llistat de llibres:");

            for (int x = 0; x < comptador; x++)
            {

                for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
                {


                    if (y == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ISBN: "+ llibres[x, y]);
                    }
                    else if (y == 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Títol: " + llibres[x, y]);
                    }
                    else if (y == 2)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Autor: " + llibres[x, y]);
                    }
                    else if (y == 3)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Editorial: " + llibres[x, y]);
                    }
                    else if (y == 4)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Any de edició: " + llibres[x, y]);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------");

                }
            }

        }


        static void consultaTitol(string[,] llibres)
        {

        }


        public static int menuPrincipal()
        {
            int opcio = 0;
            bool entradaValida = false;
            ConsoleKeyInfo cki;

            escriureMenu();

            do
            {
                cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
                if (Char.IsNumber(cki.KeyChar))
                {
                    opcio = Int32.Parse(cki.KeyChar.ToString());

                    if (opcio > 6 || opcio < 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("El nombre ha d'estar entre 1 i 6, torna a provar");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        entradaValida = true;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    opcio = 0;
                    Console.WriteLine("La opció ha de ser un nombre, torna a provar");
                }

            } while (!entradaValida);
            return opcio;
        }
        public static void escriureMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-----------");
            Console.WriteLine("|Llibreria|");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------");
            Console.WriteLine("1 - Afegeix un llibre");
            Console.WriteLine("2 - Donar de baixa un llibre");
            Console.WriteLine("3 - Llistat de llibres");
            Console.WriteLine("4 - Consulta per títol");
            Console.WriteLine("5 - Sortir");
        }


        static char espera()
        {
            char opcio;
            bool entradaValida = false;

            Console.WriteLine("vols continuar? s/n");
            do
            {
                opcio = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

                if (opcio != 's' && opcio != 'n')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("La opció només pot ser s o n, en minúscules");
                }
                else
                {
                    entradaValida = true;
                }
            } while (!entradaValida);

            return opcio;
        }

        static void sortida()
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

> Bien, la cuestión es que en la función de eliminar o dar de baja un
>   libro, no sé cómo puedo eliminar los elementos de un array
>   bidimensional, el algoritmo sería algo así (dejo la función citada primero):

```
    static void eliminaLlibre(ref string[,] llibres, ref int comptador)
    {
        string isbn;
        bool trobat = false;
        int posicioX = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Entra el ISBN del llibre que vols donar de baixa:");
        isbn = Console.ReadLine();


        for (int x = 0; x < comptador; x++)
        {
            if (llibres[x, 0] == isbn)
            {
                trobat = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                posicioX++;
            }
        }


        if (!trobat)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Llibre trobat a la base de dades, donant de baixa");
            comptador--;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No s'ha pogut trobar el libre, Comrpvoa que el ISBN sigui correcte o que el llibre es trobi a la base de dades");
        }

    }
```

Con un bucle for recorro la primera casilla, la cual equivale al ISBN, entonces a partir de ahí, una vez encontrado, sólo me queda avanzar horizontalmente e ir borrando dichos elementos, y eso último es lo que no se cómo puedo hacerlo. Lo cual me lleva a otra duda:

> Una vez eliminado el elemento, lo ideal sería que al volver a ingresar
>   otro libro en la base de datos, se ingresara en la misma posición en
>   que estaba el eliminado, y ahí ya si que ando perdido del todo, alguna
>   idea? muchas gracias desde ya!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código tiene varios problemas.El principal problema que tienes se deriva de la estructura de datos que estas utilizando. Un array es como si tuvieras una estanteria con libros. Puedes meter un libro en un estante, y puedes quitarlo de el, pero el hueco siempre va a estar.

En tu caso, una lista `List` sería mas apropiada, ya que en esa estructura no tienes que preocuparte de buscar la posición libre para meter un nuevo libro, simplemente añades y se coloca al final. A la hora de eliminar lo mismo, buscas el libro a eliminar, lo quitas y ya no debes preocuparte de nada mas.

Por otro lado, cuando estás añadiendo un nuevo libro, no entiendo porque usas un bucle para usar una sola posición del array,cuando puedes usar `llibres[comptador]...`.

Otro detalle es que en lugar de utilizar un array bidimensional para meter en la segunda dimension los campos de cada libro tampoco es lo adecuado. Lo lógico es crear una clase `Libro` que tenga los campos necesarios,algo asi:

```
class Libro
{
     public string ISBN {get;set;}
     public string Titulo {get;set;}
     public string Autor {get;set;}
     public string Editorial {get;set;}
     public string Año {get;set;}
}
```

De esta manera, usarías una lista definida como : `List<Libro> lista= new List<Libro>();`

El proceso para añadir un libro, buscarlo y eliminarlo es asi de simple:

```
//Añadimos un nuevo libro
lista.Add(new Libro(){ ISBN = "ABCD", 
                       Titulo = "titulo", 
                       Autor = "autor",
                       Editorial = "ed", 
                       Año = "1999" });

//Buscamos el libro con ISBN="ABCD"
Libro lib=lista.Where(x => x.ISBN == "ABCD").FirstOrDefault();

//Eliminamos el libro que acabamos de encontrar
lista.Remove(lib);

//Mostrar lista completa de libros
foreach(Libro l in lista)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ISBN: " + l.ISBN);
    Console.WriteLine("Titulo: " + l.Titulo);
    Console.WriteLine("Autor: " + l.Autor);
    Console.WriteLine("Editorial: " + l.Editorial);
    Console.WriteLine("Año: " + l.Año);
}
```

Como ves, de esta manera el proceso es muy sencillo y claro. Espero que te ayude.

Comment: Vale, muchísimas gracias, me ha sido de mucha utilidad, ahora me quedan un par de dudas respecto a tu comentario: primero, en Libro lib=lista.Where(x => x.ISBN == "ABCD").FirstOrDefault(); cual es la función o propósito de x? y luego, la lista se muestra igual que un array? De no ser así cómo podría mostrar la lista de libros completos? muchas gracias!

Comment: Esa linea hace uso de [Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb397676.aspx), una tecnologia muy util a la hora de hacer consultas de datos. En este caso, `x` lo que hace es representar el valor de cada uno de los libros (yo lo he llamado x, puedes poner cualquier nombre), de tal manera que lo que hace es devolver todas las filas que tengan en ISBN el valor `ABCD`. A eso se le aplica `FirstOrDefault` para que solo devuelva la primera que encuentre, o `null`si no encuentra ninguna.

Comment: En cuanto a mostrar la lista completa de libros, mira en la respuesta que acabo de editar. Basicamente es utilizar un `foreach` para ir recorriendo todos los elementos y mostrar cada una de sus propiedades. Si aun asi quisieras convertirlo a un array, podrias hacer simplemente `Libro[] libros=lista.ToArray<Libro>();`

Comment: Perfecto, ya tengo el código casi acabado, y lo he entendido muy muy bien, aunque me falta una última cosa, tengo la parte en que me piden que se pueda consultar un libro a través de su título, dando así toda la información del mismo, tengo claro cómo debería hacerlo, pero no se cómo mostrar toda la información de la lista que esté relacionada con el título, sería lo último que me haría falta, de veras muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Pues es igual de sencillo: `Libro lib=lista.Where(x => x.Titulo == "Titulo").FirstOrDefault();` Con esto tendrías el libro que tenga "Titulo" en el titulo en `lib`, y luego no es mas que `Console.WriteLine("ISBN: " + lib.ISBN);...`

Comment: Por cierto, si esto son deberes(si lo se no te lo habría dado tan mascado, lo interesante es que lo hagas tu)  es posible que te pongan pegas por usar Linq para obtener los datos, ya que el ejercicio probablemente trate de aprender a manejar las estructuras de datos y los bucles `for`,`foreach`etc...

Comment: Lo son, pero mi intención no era que me dieran nada mascado, llevo rato buscando para qué sirve y cómo funciona todo lo que me has explicado, debido a que no sabía ni cómo funcionaba la creación de clases, el profesor no nos explica mucho que digamos, simplemente nos pone los ejercicios "y ya nos espabilaremos", así que muchas gracias por toda la ayuda, y como digo no me he dedicado a hacer copy paste, de hecho lo que me has explicado me va a ayudar mucho durante el curso, así que, de nuevo, muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Si es asi y efectivamente lo has entendido todo, me alegro de haberte ayudado, de eso se trata :)